# The code below is supposed to return the least perfect square that when added to it, the sum is also a perfect square

Tags: ruby

So suppose I give 13 as n, the code should return 36 because 36 is the least perfect square that when added to 13 it gives 49 which is a perfect square. Now when I give 4 as n, it should return -1 because 4 added to all the numbers has no perfect square hence it's returning nothing. The code works without adding the elsif but that means if I pass in 4 it will return the range. But once I add the elsif it still prints out the range.

```
def solve n
    arr = (1..10).each do |i|
    i = (i**2) + n
    if (Math.sqrt(i) % 1) == 0 
          return i - n
    elsif false
          return -1
    end
    
  end  
  arr
end



p solve(13) #= 36
# # because 36 is the smallest perfect square that can be added to 13 to form a perfect square => 13 + 36 = 49

p solve(3) #= 1 # 3 + 1 = 4, a perfect square
p solve(12) #= 4 # 12 + 4 = 16, a perfect square
p solve(9) #= 16 
p solve(4) #= -1
```

Comment: `elsif false` doesn't make any sense. Since `false` is always - eh - _false_ (pun intended), the `return -1` won't ever be executed. Instead, if `Math.sqrt(i) % 1` is not zero, `nil` will be returned, because you don't have an `else` branch.

Comment: You can enumerate square numbers via basic addition: 1² = 1, 2² = 1 + 3, 3² = 1 + 3 + 5, 4² = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 and so on. So you _could_ solve that problem without `**` or `sqrt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is your code is never entering to the `elsif` branch, that's why you're getting the `(1..10)` range after the iteration because that's the value `arr` holds and as there's no return value after checking if `(Math.sqrt(i) % 1) == 0`.

You could just return -1 if there was no a explicit return during the iteration:

```
def solve n
  (1..10).each do |i|
    i = (i**2) + n
    return i - n if (Math.sqrt(i) % 1).zero?
  end
  -1
end

solve(3)  # 1
solve(12) # 4
solve(9)  # 16
solve(4)  # -1
```

Comment: This does work Sebastian. But would it work for an infinity loop? say (1..)?

Comment: @Martin how does the infinite loop break if there's no solution?

Comment: by returning -1 as Sebastian wrote

Comment: With an endless range it'd work different @Martin, if you don't get `(Math.sqrt(i) % 1).zero?` to return true, it'll take a long-long time running - for not saying forever.

Comment: @Martin an infinite loop doesn't reach the `-1`.

Comment: @Stefan you are right.. so I put n instead of (1..10) I did (1..n)

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma, just realized that